# How to properly check and log http status code using promises and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, es6-promise

I am new to JavaScript and very new to node.js framework, just started using it a few days ago. My apologies if my code is nonsensical, the whole idea of promises and callbacks is still sinking in. That being said my question is the following I am trying to figure out if certain request to websites are successful or cause an error based on the range of their status code response. I am working with an array of websites and what I've done so far is below, I do however get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on my local machine with node.js installed and can't figure out why.

```js
const sample = [
    'http://www.google.com/',
    'http://www.spotify.com/us/',
    'http://twitter.com/',
    'http://google.com/nothing'
]

const http = require('http')

const getStatusCodeResult = (website) => {

    http.get(website, (res) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                let statusCode = res.statusCode
                error = statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 500 ? `error: ${website}`: null
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                    
                } else if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 300) {
                    resolve(`Success: ${website}`)
                }
            }, 0)
        })
    })
}
// LOOP PROMISES
const getAllStatusCodeResult = (websites) => {
    websites.forEach((website) => {
        getStatusCodeResult(website)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error', error)
            })
    })
}
getAllStatusCodeResult(sample)
```

Ideally I would want the result to be printed as the example below, but for now I am just using `console.log` to figure out if the code even works.

```
   // Example Printout
   {
      success: ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.spotify.com/us/', 
      'https://twitter.com /' ],
      error: [''http://google.com/nothing']
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mixed up the first two lines. The `new Promise` wrapper that gets you the value to return needs to be on the outside, and the `http.get` call should be inside its executor callback. Also you don't really need that timeout:

```
function getStatusCodeResult(website) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(website, (res) => {
            let statusCode = res.statusCode,
                error = statusCode >= 400 && statusCode <= 500 ? `error: ${website}`: null
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            } else if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 300) {
                resolve(`Success: ${website}`)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome, can you please explain why the promise wraps the `http.get` is that the way its always used you wrap the referencing environment whit the promise? Also, do you by any chance know why I am only getting `error error: http://google.com/nothing
Success: http://www.google.com/` and not the rest of sites.

Comment: Yes, you always wrap the asynchronous function within the `new Promise` constructor. How you resolve and reject is usually different though

Comment: If you're not getting anything from the other promises, it's likely that the response were neither 400<=status<500 nor 200<=status<300. If there's a redirect or a server error, you never settle the promise (which is a bad thing!), so neither of your callbacks would run.

Comment: @Bergi would it be beneficial for me to add a solution using `util.promisify()` or should I not bother?

Comment: @Bergi do you think I should post a different question, about not logging all the sites in the sample array only logging  `http://google.com/nothing ` and `http://www.google.com/`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Please go for it. (Also I didn't check the `http.get` signature in the docs, it's kinda suspicious that there's no error parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_promisified_functions), you can convert `http.get()` into a promise-based asynchronous method, but first there's some preparation to do since it does not follow the convention of `callback(error, response) { ... }`:

```
const http = require('http')
const { promisify } = require('util')

// define a custom promisified version of `http.get()`
http.get[promisify.custom] = (options) => new Promise(resolve => {
  http.get(options, resolve)
});

// convert callback to promise
const httpGet = promisify(http.get)

async function getStatusCodeResult(website) {
  const res = await httpGet(website)
  const status = res.statusCode
  const message = `${http.STATUS_CODES[status]}: ${website}`

  if (status >= 400) {
    throw message
  } else {
    return message
  }
}
```

In addition, you can use [`http.STATUS_CODES`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_status_codes) to get the the appropriate message for each possible `statusCode` rather than returning a vague `Error` or `Success`.

Comment: I wonder, shouldn't `http.get[promisify.custom]` be native in node already?

Comment: @Bergi I checked, it's not defined.